# What to do with the .git folder in a WordPress plugin during local development

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a WordPress plugin. I have initialized git (`git init`) in my plugin folder. This created a hidden .git folder in the root directory.

I have to test some functionality for which I have to uninstall the plugin. To do this I have to actually delete the plugin via the WordPress plugin dashboard.

Whenever I click uninstall I'm greeted by the following message:

> "Could not fully remove the plugin plugin-name/plugin-name.php"

I figured this has to do with the hidden .git folder not being removed. When I manually remove the .git folder and then click uninstall, the uninstall proceeds as it's supposed to.

**Am I overlooking something here, is there a way of handling this during local development?**

Or is there some better way of approaching this issue?

Comment: It should not be necessary to track the entire plugins folder in Git, as I presume most of your plugins are 3rd party - you do not maintain them yourself - so just track each plugin as a submodule - also, why do you need to delete the plugin to deactivate it?

Comment: I'm only tracking the plugin I'm creating. So in my case, my plugin resides in the folder "adb-homepage-planner". So in that folder I have setup git to track everything I do, since I do have full control over the contents of that folder. It's really only a local problem, since the .git folder would never be uploaded to SVN or GIT.

I have some delete_option calls in the the uninstall.php file which I want to make sure run properly, that's why I actually had to delete the plugin so that I could afterwards go to the database and see if the options got removed.

Comment: Yeh.. if you delete the plugin - if you use sub modules for example - this also needs to delete the Git data - which is an issue with the set-up.. you would not lose anything if you have pushed your updates to a repo, but the complete delete might be blocked if Git files are in use, for example if you are editing the code in your editor at the same time..

Comment: If the .git folder is in plugins/ and not plugins/adb-homepage-planner then I'd be surprised if that was the problem. Is this Linux or Windows? If it's Windows, does something have that file open to lock it?

Comment: I made sure to close the files in the file editor, so there's no system process blocking the local delete. But it still seems to have an issue deleting the .git folder. But I will look into submodules! Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Rup, the .git folder is in plugins/adb-homepage-planner. I tried editing to my initial thread to make this more clear, sorry for the confusion!